# LLVM debug output through rust

Tags: rust, llvm, address-sanitizer

I am looking for a way to read the LLVM debug output by invoking the rust compiler (through cargo). I am especially interested in output of LLVMs ASAN.

To run a build with ASAN I can do:

```
cargo clean && RUSTFLAGS="-Zsanitizer=address" cargo build
```

but I don't know the command to get the debug log ouput.

With clang I think one can add

```
-mllvm -debug-only=asan
```

as compiler-flag.

How can I supply something like this flag through rustc?

I am using the current rust source (https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/ commit 31f5d69) to build rustc myself.

Comment: have you checked this https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-guide/blob/master/src/compiler-debugging.md

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I checked that before, but I overlooked the link to https://rust-lang.github.io/rustc-guide/codegen/debugging.html .
There, the usage of "-C llvm-args" is presented briefly. I will use this and write the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent compiler argument for rustc is

```
-C llvm-args=-debug-only=<LLVM DEBUG_TYPE>
```

The `-C` part gives access to the options for code generation of rust.

The `llvm-args` part tells rustc to forward every subsequent flag to LLVM. If I understand correctly, you can specify every LLVM option that is evaluated with `cl::opt()` in LLVM source code.

So the full command to build a rust application with ASAN and see only the log output of ASAN would be:

```
cargo clean && RUSTFLAGS="-C llvm-args=-debug-only=asan -Zsanitizer=address" cargo build
```

Side note: I think debug mode for LLVM must be enabled in config.toml when building rust to see the respective log output.